# Use StyleCop checkin policy with StyleCop+

Tags: c#, tfs, stylecop, stylecop-plus

I have a StyleCop and StyleCop+ which are integrated into projects via [StyleCop.MSBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.MSBuild/).
All warnings related to StyleCop+ are shown correctly after project build. I need to integrate my rules with [StyleCop checkin policy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RalphJansen.StyleCopCheck-inPolicy2019). Now during checkin StyleCop warnings are shown as errors, but I see that StyleCop+ warnings are not considered as errors.

Not sure if it's possible, but can I force checkin policy to handle StyleCop+ warnings as errors during checkin? (like it's working for plain StyleCop)

**[UPDATE]**
I need to produce errors only during checkin and only for files which are changed because it's an old project and I want to force others to fix only those files which they change during checkin. By default this is working properly for all warnings of StyleCop but not for warnings of StyleCop+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just took sources of [StyleCop checkin policy](https://github.com/LockTar/StyleCop-Check-in-Policy), added reference to StyleCopPlus.dll for CheckinPolicy project, did rebuild of Vsix2019 and now VSIX supports StyleCop+.